# How to install Spring boot app on Ubuntu server?

Tags: spring, ubuntu, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I have Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean and I wrote Spring web app and now I want to put it in production.

I upload it via FTP to the server and I open my console via Putty and I use this command:

```
java -jar name.jar
```

Spring is started after that and when I open my web app everything is working fine, but when I close my Putty session my Spring web app does not work anymore. It seems like when I close my Putty session that also Spring web app is closed.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `java -jar name.jar &` and the application is started in new process thread.

by adding also `> log.txt` directly at the end you would also have a log.

Comment: I will try that. If I want to stop Spring web app, how I can do that?

Comment: `ps aux | grep java` will show you the list of java processes.

Comment: with `kill -9 PID` you would be able to kill a running process

Comment: `-9` kills the process with iron fist. PID needs to be replace with the process id.

Answer (score 4):

While what [KLHauser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5663017/klhauser) suggested will work, but if the vm is restarted in the cloud (which happens) your application will not automatically restart. Also stopping your application with `kill -9` is error prone and dangerous, because you accidentally may kill the wrong process.

See running as Linux service section of [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) documentation on how to do that.

> If you’ve configured Spring Boot’s Maven or Gradle plugin to generate
>   a fully executable jar, and you’re not using a custom
>   `embeddedLaunchScript`, then your application can be used as an `init.d`
>   service. Simply symlink the jar to `init.d` to support the standard
>   start, stop, restart and status commands.
>
> The script supports the following features:
>
> - Starts the services as the user that owns the jar file
> - Tracks
>     application’s PID using /var/run//.pid
> - Writes
>     console logs to /var/log/.log
>
> Assuming that you have a Spring Boot application installed in
>   `/var/myapp`, to install a Spring Boot application as an init.d service
>   simply create a symlink:
>
> `$ sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp` Once installed,
>   you can start and stop the service in the usual way. For example, on a
>   Debian based system:
>
> `$ service myapp start`

Comment: So I can upload my jar to some folder and than install it with /etc/init.d/myapp and I can easily start it and stop it later, am I right?

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation, where `myapp` is the name of your app

Comment: In my case i've received this messaged <code>Failed to start autobio.service: Unit autobio.service failed to load: No such file or directory.</code>. After running <code>update-rc.d myapp defaults</code> it was working. (System: SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old thread, but I have placed my application's jar file in var/myapp and can run it. However when I navigate to my server's IP im just shown the empty var/www/hmtl directory. Can anyone help? @jny